# Apex - Insert json value into custom field

Tags: apex, trigger, json, object, insert

I am inserting records into custom object Rating__c via trigger.

This object has a field that stores json value against each record based on Account ID(Related Account).
Example:

```
{"attributes":{"type":"Rating__c","url":"/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Rating__c/0014...."},"Contact__c":"0034...","Id":"0014"}
```

My code:

```
String jsonString;
for(Account acc : account) {
   Rating__c rating = new Rating__c();
   rating.Account__c = acc.Id;
   rating.Contact__c = acc.Contact__c;
   rating.Stage__c = acc.Stage__c;
   // Unable to Construct right value for JSON here 
   jsonString = '{"attributes":"type":"Account","url":"/services/data/v54.0/sobjects/Account/"'+acc.Id+',"Contact__c":"'+ acc.Contact__c +',"Id":"'+acc.Id +'"}';

   rating.jsonValue__c = json.serialize(jsonString );
   
}
```

How do I build the desired JSON string ?

Comment: There is no such OOTB field `acc.Contact`

Comment: @cropredy Sorry, I've updated the code snippet here. Not specific to a field but my question is related to how I can create such json structure and insert it as a field value. Kindly guide me as I am a new dev. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This works with one caveat

```
for(Account acc : account) {
   Account accJsonCondensed = new Account(
    Id = acc.Id,
    Name = acc.Name,
    ...
   );
   
   Rating__c rating = new Rating__c(
      Account__c = acc.Id,
      Contact__c = acc.Contact__c,
      Stage__c = acc.Stage__c,
      JsonValue__c = JSON.serialize(accJsonCondensed,true) /* ignore nulls */
   );
   ... do something with rating like add to a list for DML
  }
```

**Caveat**

If the length of field `Rating__c.JsonValue__c` is too small to fit the serialized Account `acc`, then you will get a *field length exceeded* exception.  This could happen if your Account object has several text area long fields that are populated with long values.

The only way to avoid this would be to serialize a clone of `acc` that you construct with only the relevant fields to serialize that you are confident will fit within the length constraints of `Rating__c.JsonValue__c`

Comment: Thanks for the response. How can I serialize a clone of acc, I just need a couple of fields from acc and not all. Tried to build it as jsonString in my code, but unsure if that's the right way. @cropredy

Comment: Account accClone = acc.clone(true);  then populate fields as needed.

Comment: Thanks @cropredy. Should I be cloning it in the for loop itself? Will give it a try

Comment: Still unable to achieve this, I dont want to clone the entire object. Just need to construct few fields in the JSON format. Please help

Comment: made an adjustment;